# WSO2IS-Axis2 Connections are not getting closed properly. It stays in CLOSE_WAIT state until reach maximum open file limit

Tags: playframework, apache-axis, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2IS 5.3.0 with Play framework. I am getting "Too many open files" error on my server once in a month. When I investigate the error I found that Axis2 connections in WSO2 is not getting closed, it loads Axis2 WSO2 jars in /tmp folder and stays in (CLOSE_WAIT) state that causing memory full error. For every new connection it is loading the same WSO2 jars in different folder under /tmp directory once again.

Answer (score 0):

Found a bug. When I upgrade WSO2IS from 5.1.0-beta to 5.3.0, missed out to upgrade the jars. The issue is fixed after upgrading axis2 jar from axis2_1.6.1.wso2v14.jar to axis2_1.6.1.wso2v20.jar

Comment: Great to know that you have fixed the issue. But it is always recommended to flow the migration guide during migration https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Migration+Guide . If you are building the prodct from the source always checkout to a release version

Comment: Yes right. I am using some WSO2 APIs in my Java project so added wso2 jars to the project. Unfortunately I forgot to update 
 those jars when I was upgrading WSO2IS version.